# Mongodb to fetch top 100 results for each category

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of transactions that has below schema:

```
{
  _id,
  client_id,
  billings,
  date,
  total 
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the 10 latest transaction models based on the date for a list of client IDs. I don't think the `$slice` well as the use case is mostly for embedded arrays.

Currently, I am iterating through the client_ids and using find with the limit but it is extremely slow.

**UPDATE**

**Example**

https://mongoplayground.net/p/urKH7HOxwqC

This shows two clients with 10 transaction each on different days, I want to write a query that would return latest 5 transaction for each.

Any suggestions of how to query data to make it faster?

Comment: What version of the database are you on?

Comment: need more info its hard to understand

Comment: @AmitWagner updated the answer. Using mongo 4.2

Comment: first, put an index on **date**
then you can sort by date push the items and the slice them in aggregate(if there are a lot of results then you will need to filter some) do you filter by client_id?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to just execute multiple queries, 1 for each client, like so:

```
const clients = await db.collection.distinct('client_id');
const results = await Promise.all(
    clients.map((clientId) => db.collection.find({client_id: clientId}).sort({date: -1}).limit(5))
)
```

To improve this performance make sure you have an index on `client_id` and `date`. If for whatever reason you can't built these indexes I'd recommend using this following pipeline (with syntax available starting version 5.3+):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$client_id",
      latestTransactions: {
        "$bottomN": {
          "n": 5,
          "sortBy": {
            "date": 1
          },
          "output": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LSx2tb5k50L)